# Cross browser - aesthetic fault with my buttons

Tags: css, cross-browser

I am trying to make language buttons.

First problem was the round background, fixed that.
Second problem was the animation of the background, fixed that.

now in FF the buttons have an ugly line when on hover.

here is the link.

[The code I'm working on](http://edizarca.com/karpaz/)

Can anyone please explain to me, what has gone wrong here so I can try to fix it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Force the `.selected` style to apply by giving it importance.

```css
background: #FFF600 !important;
```

Since Firefox has a display issue with `box-shadow`, use `border` instead.

```css
border: 0.5em solid #FFF600;
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aJv2w/2/).

Fixed a bunch of other issues as well, including:

```css
#languages li { display: inline-block; width: 45px; }
```

since border takes up some space, and removed `display:block;` from `#languages li a`.

Comment: Ok this fixes it I see, but theres an issue. The transition does not smoothly go back to its first state when hover is no longer.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your styles:

```
#languages li a.selected {
background: yellow;
}
```

This should color the middle of the circle too.

Considering the FF issue, I can't help you with that.

Comment: I never said it did. This solves the _".selected class should be making the middle of the circle yellow too."_ problem

Comment: ok thank you. selectivity was the problem on that one. I just noticed.

Answer (score 0):

when you use certain attributes like **box-shadow** you should use **-moz-box-shadow** also, with the same parameters.  Use it like you would use webkit, just with moz instead. 
Try adding **-moz-border-radius**

Also, try a background clip?

```
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box; 
    -moz-background-clip:    padding; 
    background-clip:         padding-box;
```